# Ordinal exponentiation --- Kunen / Set theory Exercise I.13.39

Tags: set-theory, exponentiation, ordinals

Exercise I.13.39 in **Kunen**'s *Set Theory*:

> If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $\alpha = \cup_{n < c}X_n$,
> where $c < \omega$ and each $\textrm{type}(X_n) < \kappa^\omega$, then
> $\alpha < \kappa^\omega$.

Using $\textrm{type}(X_n)$ implies that $X_n$ are well-ordered.
Does the claim should be modified to:
$\textbf{type}(\alpha) < \kappa^\omega$ ?

Should we also assume that the union definition of $\alpha$
is well ordered consistent with the well-ordering of each $X_n$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting from context, $\alpha$ is already assumed to be an ordinal. We simply say that if we can write this ordinal as a finite union of sets, each of whom has order type $<\kappa^\omega$, then $\alpha$ is also smaller than $\kappa^\omega$.

Since the $X_n$ are assumed to be subsets of $\alpha$, they are naturally well-ordered.